# Error $.get(...).done is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I have code that looks like that:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function draw(){

var a = 0,
    timeC = 0,
    timeS = 0,
meanCFf=0,
meanSFf= 0;

$.get('test1.csv').done(function(data) {
var i, 
    lines = data.split('\n'),
    line = lines[0].split(','),
    oS = line.indexOf('oS'),
    browName = line.indexOf('browName'),
    browVer = line.indexOf('browVer'),
    timeCanvas = line.indexOf('timeCanvas'),
    timeSvg = line.indexOf('timeSvg'); 
for(i=1; i<lines.length; i++) {
    line = lines[i].split(',');
    if(line[oS] === 'Windows') {
        a++;
        timeC += parseFloat(line[timeCanvas], 10);
        timeS += parseFloat(line[timeSvg], 10);
    }
}
});
    meanCFf = timeC/a;
meanSFf = timeC/a;
var os1 = document.getElementById("osInfo1");
os1.innerHTML = "Twoja średnia  to: " + meanCFf;
var os2 = document.getElementById("osInfo2");
os2.innerHTML = "Twój sytem operacyjny to: " + meanSFf;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="draw()">
    <p id="osInfo1"></p>
    <p id="osInfo2"></p>
</body>
```

And I get an error Unhandled Error: '$.get('test1.csv').done' is not a function, I tried to google this error but I don't understand the answer its some kind of name problem?? From what i googled I tried to change $ for jQuery  but still got the same error

Comment: Deferreds / promises have been introduced in jQuery 1.5. You are using 1.3. You should use the latest version instead.

Comment: hmm i seen that solution somewhere in google but i was sure that i have the newest version so i didnt check. Thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used old jquery, Try using latest jquery version

Answer (score 1):

The [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) was introduced in jQuery **1.5**. You seem to be using jquery **1.3**. So make sure that you upgrade to jQuery **1.5** if you want to use [`deferred objects`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Deferred).

If for some reason you cannot upgrade you could use the `success` callback of the `$.get` function:

```
$.get('test1.csv', function(data) {
    var i, 
    lines = data.split('\n'),
    line = lines[0].split(','),
    oS = line.indexOf('oS'),
    browName = line.indexOf('browName'),
    browVer = line.indexOf('browVer'),
    timeCanvas = line.indexOf('timeCanvas'),
    timeSvg = line.indexOf('timeSvg'); 

    for(i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
        line = lines[i].split(',');
        if(line[oS] === 'Windows') {
            a++;
            timeC += parseFloat(line[timeCanvas], 10);
            timeS += parseFloat(line[timeSvg], 10);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery version you used is too low, please use higher jquery version run your code.